# Windows Powershell run script with absolute path

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a script I want to run in Windows PowerShell. It works fine when using a relative path, but not with the absolute path. How can I make this work with an absolute path as well?

Example:

Running this from the terminal works (run from C: dir)

```
PS C:\> .\venvs\my_venv\Scripts\activate
(my_venv) PS C:\>
```

This does not work

```
PS C:\> C:\venvs\my_venv\Scripts\activate
PS C:\>
```

I'm expecting

```
PS C:\> C:\venvs\my_venv\Scripts\activate
(my_venv) PS C:\>
```

Comment: You need to add `PowerShell ` in front of it, like so: `PowerShell c:\path\to\script\PowerShellScript.ps1`

Comment: nope that doesn't work for me. it's also not a ps1 script

Comment: `PowerShell -File "path"` should work. Or for PS 7 `pwsh -f "path"`

Comment: Nope, `Processing -File 'C:\repos\venvs\my_venv\Scripts\activate' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension.`

Comment: Why doesn't it have the extension? Why can't you set it?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't have that extension, it's coming from https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win. In any case, running it with a relative path as shown above works perfectly fine using powershell. I also tried adding `ps1` as extension to the file, that didn't work either.

Comment: @emilaz - You need to put the filename and it's extension.  Verify the file doesn't have to file extensions. I was able to execute the file myself within a Windows 10 VM

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean exactly? You need to be way more specific with your question & comments now. Are you sure that file is PowerShell script in the 1st place? I don't recall virtual env activators being PowerShell files on Windows.

Comment: Simply nothing happens, no error message, but the virtual env is also not activated

Comment: 1. Does it work with absolute path if run by Administrator? Could be C: [root] access issue (and yes, .\ does effectively give that access, so I don't claim this is an answer). 2. Is this script for a VM? If so, the root drive called C: on the VM is *not* necessarily the PC's root drive, but that in the VM. You might need to make the path `Z:\venvs\my_venv\Scripts\activate`, for example.

Comment: The extension not showing could just be a Windows settings of File Options to not show file extensions. I'd go with testing from `@DrMoishePippik` listed to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me. Execute the Activate.ps1 file that is also auto-generated when the virtual environment is created instead of activate. Tested with Python 3.11.0 and virtualenv 20.20.0.

```
PS C:\> C:\...\pyenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Here is a full commented log:

```shell
PS C:\Users\justinw> python -m venv pyenv

# activates as expected
PS C:\Users\justinw> .\pyenv\Scripts\activate
(pyenv) PS C:\Users\justinw> deactivate

# doesn't activate as expected
PS C:\Users\justinw> C:\Users\justinw\pyenv\Scripts\activate

# activates using absolute path
PS C:\Users\justinw> C:\Users\justinw\pyenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
(pyenv) PS C:\Users\justinw> deactivate

# FYI on default Scripts created
PS C:\Users\justinw> ls .\pyenv\Scripts\


    Directory: C:\Users\justinw\pyenv\Scripts


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM           2064 activate
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM            993 activate.bat
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM          24167 Activate.ps1
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM            393 deactivate.bat
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM         108400 pip.exe
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM         108400 pip3.10.exe
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM         108400 pip3.11.exe
-a----         4/22/2023  11:14 AM         108400 pip3.exe
-a----         4/22/2023  11:13 AM         268152 python.exe
-a----         4/22/2023  11:13 AM         256384 pythonw.exe
PS C:\Users\justinw>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run with a point before and within single quotes or double quotes (in case there are spaces in path names):

```
.'C:\> C:\...\pyenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1'
```